# Cross-platform native/managed interface

Tags: .net, mono, c++-cli, interop

I have a few native C++ libraries and such that I need to expose to managed (C#, in this case) code. I need to get as much speed out of it as possible.

I would like to use some classes to simplify the interaction, which means mixed code, but that's not a requirement.

What is a requirement is that it be cross-platform compatible, to Windows and Linux at worst. Thus, standard /clr is out of the question.

My options are either /clr:pure or /clr:safe, or embedding Mono into a go-between layer. My question is which will be better (best performance and ease of development and later use).

The libraries I need to work with make heavy use of pointers and occasionally shared pointers, which made me think the C++/CLI layer would be easier. I wrote a simple app testing use of some objects and compiled it with /clr:pure, it didn't link into the native module but did run under both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use P/Invoke.

Using 'pure' will make it a lot slower from what I have seen, especially number crunching stuff (encryption).

Comment: Pure generates p/invoke calls automatically, so I don't see why it would be slower.  Just recognize that the interface is expensive and don't make it chatty (minimize the number of calls, use primitive types where possible).

Comment: Pure definitely shouldn't be slower than doing it in C#, so it's not really an issue. My main interest is C++'s management of pointers and any benefits that might provide for an interface layer. Any data that does go between will be pointers in 90% of the functions (and so blittable and little marshaling cost), but I need to work with some unmanaged classes on occasion. That's why /clr:pure was a thought, as most docs suggest it allows limited use of unmanaged libraries and classes.

Comment: C++/CLI in /clr:pure mode handles pointers the same way C# in /unsafe mode does.  Of course, it's still much easier in C++/CLI because you can just #include the native struct definition -- in C# you have to recreate the structure definition with explicit layout attributes.  Ditto for functions, in C++/CLI just #include the header file, in C# you have to write p/invoke declarations and annotate them properly with charset attributes etc.  But the resulting MSIL shouldn't be much different.